# I have set all JDK / JRE environment variables correctlly but fails to install Eclipse.

Tags: java, eclipse

When I run "java" and "javac" on CMD it gives what it suppose to.

Also my apache-tomcat server is running which means all the environment variables and path are set correctly.

However it fails to install ECLIPSE giving "JRE Missing" page.

Where should I start looking for?

Comment: Check `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks problem solved.